# Point features appear in PDF export when they shouldn't

Tags: qgis, point, export, pdf

I'm using QGIS and have some issues when exporting maps using point layers.

In this case, I've simply displayed proportional circles from a point layer using the size assistant, setting their minimum size to 0. The circles are set with a thin outline.

The result looks fine on the project itself and on the PNG export: the points whose value equals 0 can't be seen. Thus there's no issue with their outline I assume. [image: PNG export - no points can be seen here]

However, these points, which shouldn't be displayed, are still visible on the PDF export. [image: PDF export - thin points can be seen]

The same issue can occur when point layers are solely used to display labels (with the label property), in which case the underlying point should be invisible.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of showing the points with a size of 0, you can filter them out.

In the graduated style (or any type of style), instead of choosing the `val` column, use the expression `if (val>0, val,null)` which will style only the points having a positive value.

Since the points are filtered-out, make sure that the 1st point size is now greater than zero!

The PDF export looks fine for the filtered points.

[image: Style data filter]